# How to know which docker base image will be right one for the requirement from all images of DockerHub?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-image

How can I know which Docker Base image will be the best one for the requirement out of all the related images available in DockerHub?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that doesn't have an exact answer: what base image to use will depend on multiple factors, and even after considering those, you'll probably have multiple alternatives.

[Here's an article that talks about this same question](https://www.ca.com/en/blog-developers/docker-containers-os-base-image.html), and goes into detail about some tips when choosing. The conclusion ends up being:

> To summarize, selecting the appropriate OS base image depends on the
>   following factors:
>
> - What technologies are used to build the application being containerized?
> - What is the intended target platform on which these images will run?
> - What is the desirable size of the application image? (including all layers and base images)
> - Pure Taste!

Still, always make sure to check DockerHub for an existing image of the requirements you're looking to solve. You may be surprised and find exactly what you need!